# How to use Freemarker to convert a XML Word document to a DOC?

Tags: java, apache-poi, freemarker

I'm trying to use Freemarker to *convert* an XML Word document to a standard DOC. For example:

1. I generate a Word document (`A.doc`) and then save it as XML Word document (`A.xml`).
2. On Freemarker, I import `A.xml` and export it as 2003 Word (`B.doc`).
3. In POI, I import the converted DOC (`B.doc`). (POI *can't* read XML docs.)

The problem is: **the converted document isn't really a DOC, it's an XML doc**,
so POI fails to open it.

**How to use Freemarker generate a *real* DOC, not a XML word document?**
I'm using Linux.

Comment: `@user993109` **Welcome to StackOverflow!** I recommend you to change your username.

Comment: **Important:** I have **rewritten** your question to help others understand your problem. Please **review** and **correct** any wrong things.

Comment: [POI _can_ read DOCX documents.](http://poi.apache.org/)

Comment: My customers can only use Word 2003(DOC document).Thank you all the same.

Comment: Thank you.Your description is very accurate.

Comment: Sorry, it seems I got you wrong. POI can also create DOC documents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach probably won't work because FreeMarker is designed for generating text output. Classic Word DOC files are not very "textual", so I think FreeMarker is not the right tool for your task.

(Side note: but RTF might work)

Comment: IText can generate a RTF Word document.I will try it.Thank you.

Comment: I've been trying the Word XML format, but it's a real pain.  Word divides content by "Grammar" boundaries, separating the placeholders "${", "}" between XML elements.